# Listing by Attributes When Parsing Html in Dart & Flutter

Tags: html, flutter, parsing, dart, attributes

```
var response = await http.get('https://www....');
dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
var selectElements = document.getElementsByClassName('hello').map((item) => item.children).toList();
```

I can sort and list by classes thanks to the http library, but I don't know how to do it according to attributes. How can I list by attributes?

There is an HTML output as below. I want to list the ones whose attribute data-time is 9112020 and see the results for lorem ipsum3 and lorem ipsum4.

```
<tr class="hello" data-country="Germany" data-time="8112020">lorem ipsum1</tr>
<tr class="hello" data-country="Turkey" data-time="8112020">lorem ipsum2</tr>
<tr class="hello" data-country="Germany" data-time="9112020">lorem ipsum3</tr>
<tr class="hello" data-country="Turkey" data-time="9112020">lorem ipsum4</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `where` function to filter your items:

```dart
  var selectElements  = document
      .getElementsByClassName('hello')
      .where((element) => element.attributes['data-time'] == '9112020')
      .map((item) => item.text)
      .toList();
```

here is a GitHub gist for my full code: https://gist.github.com/ali2236/14a12460a7b8f857e9e5c02583fff91c

There also seems to be a bug with the HTML parser in my example which should not happen in the real world.